# Sending information with ajax from knockout js array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a table containing this kind of information
[image]

I am using knockout js and putting all data on a array and putting it on this table like this.

```
self.allchildrendata = ko.observableArray();
self.viewAllUserChildrenCard = function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + '/index.php/main/childrenCardInfo',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType :'json'
            })
            .done(function(childrencards) {
                self.allchildrendata.removeAll();
                $.each(childrencards, function (index, childrencard) {
                self.allchildrendata.push(childrencard);
                console.log(self.allchildrendata());
                });
            })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        };
        self.viewAllUserChildrenCard();
```

So next I want to click the add money button for rebecca and want to send the orig id of only rebecca so I can use it to find her in the database and add money, But i am not sure on how to send the orig_id, I tried this way.

```
self.giveCashtoChild = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + '/index.php/main/addUserChildrenCash' + "/" + self.allchildrendata().orig_id ,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function() {

            })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        }
```

Here is the html code where I have a databind on each of the buttons so I can send the orig id .

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: allchildrendata">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text : $data.children_name"></span></td> 
                    <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text : $data.daugther_son"></span></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text : $data.amount"></span> $</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><a href="#" data-bind="click : $root.giveCashtoChild"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/main/takeAway"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
```

So basically I need help to identify which family memeber I am clicking and sending that family memebers orig_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use a `click` binding, knockout passes the current binding's `data` and `event`.

So in your HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click : $root.giveCashtoChild">
```

It calls `giveCashToChild` with two arguments. Your `giveCashToChild` method should thus accept two arguments, of which the first will be the child to give cash to.

```
self.giveCashtoChild = function(data, event) {
  var currentChildId = data.orig_id;
  // the other stuff..
};
```

Comment: Tried it, did not work, I posted another question similar to this one, where I fixed it like 90% but ajax request is not going... Please check it out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221510/ajax-function-not-going-to-php-codeigniter-controller

Comment: Dit you also replace `self.allchildrendata().orig_id` with `currentChildId` ?

Comment: Your question was about identifying which family member is clicked by the user. Can you confirm that in my example, `currentChildId` holds the id of the clicked family member? Things might still go wrong, but I do expect this part to work... Any error logs?

Comment: Yup your answer works, so I am accepting it, but doesnt send the information to the controller.

Comment: Look at what I posted . you have access to all data of your child. this way every child has its own model . they are separate entity.

Comment: @Farhana Thanks.

@Matt.k I agree that the post method shouldn't be accessed via `$root` but should live inside a separate viewmodel. Definitely a better 'design'. I just thought that, for this question in specific, it might be nice to keep it simple.