# ajax function not going to php codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, knockout.js

I have a ajax function written which is posting different numbers.
Here is the ajax function.

```
self.giveCashtoChild = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + '/index.php/main/addUserChildrenCash'+"/"+self.selectedchild(),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function() {

            })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        }
```

self.selectedchild() has the value of 2 , so Basically the url is addUserChildrenCash/2 but then it does not go to the codeigniter controller and change the page. Here is the controller function.

```
public function addUserChildrenCash($childID){
            if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id')){
                redirect('main'); // the user is not logged in, redirect them!
            }

                $userid= $this->session->userdata('user_id');
                $this->load->model('main_page');
                $childname =  $this->main_page->getChildName($childID, $userid);

                $data = array(
                    'name' => $childname['children_name']
                );
                $this->load->view('header2_view');
                $this->load->view('add_user_children_cash_view' , $data);
                $this->load->view('footer_view');

        }
```

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter's built-in CSRF protection?  If so, then your ajax data must include the value of the hidden CSRF token field. This is the part that gets submitted with the standard form action but is missing when you do ajax.

Comment: @Sparky I am not sure what that is ?

Comment: Check for CSRF in your CodeIgniter configuration file.  See:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/security.html?highlight=csrf#csrf-protection

Comment: How can I get rid of that ? 
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

Comment: Get rid of what?  Looks like you already have it deactivated... `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE`  Although I strongly suggest you learn about what it means and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define ajax as `POST` but you sending it via `GET`

```
 type: 'POST',
 url: BASEURL + '/index.php/main/addUserChildrenCash'+"/"+self.selectedchild(),
```

So your code should be

**In Ajax**

```
var id = self.selectedchild(); # Assign data to here
$.ajax(
    {

        type:"post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/main/addUserChildrenCash", 
        data:{ id:id},
        success:function()
        {

        }
        error:function()
        {

        }
        always:function(){

        }
    });
```

**In controller**

```
public function addUserChildrenCash()
{
    $id = $this->input->post("id");
    echo $id
}
```

Comment: Tried it , not sure why its not working, I do get all variables.

Comment: `console.log(id)` and check console

Comment: did you change base url to this `<?php echo base_url(); ?>`??

Comment: console.log(id) value comes to 2 and yes i did that second one as well

Comment: oohh Happy face at end :)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.giveCashtoChild = function(){
            var id = self.selectedchild();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + '/index.php/main/addUserChildrenCash/"+id,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function() {

            })
            .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            })
            .always(function(data){                 
            });
        }
```

Comment: please use an `alert(id);` after `var id = self.selectedchild();` to see if it has the correct value

Comment: Yup has the right value of 2, but its not sending it to the controller

Answer (score 0):

In your codeigniter use case I would pass your ajax parameter like this:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: BASEURL +'/index.php/main/addUserChildrenCash',
   data: { 'childID': self.selectedchild() },
   })
  ...
```

In the codeigniter controller I would receive the parameter like this:

```
public function addUserChildrenCash() {
    $childID = $this->input->post("childID");
    ...
    }
```

You should also check wether your BASEURL has the correct value assigned. Hope this helps.

Comment: why have  CHildID inside public function addUserChildrenCash()  ?? and yea did not work :(